# Extract 1- or 2-digit month AND 4-digit year from a string where month and year can be in either order?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string

I have a DataFrame, df, with a Scenario column containing strings.  These strings have one of four patterns, ('Text' is just one word, no spaces, there is always a 4-digit year and either a 1- or 2-digit month, sometimes with leading zero and sometimes without):

1. Text 01 2018
2. Text 2 2019
3. Text 2020 03
4. Text 2021 4

I want to create a new column YearMonth which will be of type period, built from the string, e.g. 201801, 201902, 202003, 202104, etc.

I tried a regex approach, but this required me to do two searches on each string and then combine the results in the right order.

```
pattern = r'(?P<twod>\d{2}).*?(?P<fourd>\d{4})|(?P<fourd2>\d{4}).*?(?P<twod2>\d{2})'

# Find the first match in the input string
match = re.search(pattern, input_string)

if match:
    twod_number = match.group('twod') or match.group('twod2')
    fourd_number = match.group('fourd') or match.group('fourd2')
```

Is there a better way?  2 million rows, so I would prefer something better than df['Scenario'].apply if possible.  I know the position of the second space in the string tells the order of the month/year, but I don't know if that information could lead to a faster solution, (if position = 9, year = string[5:9], month = string[10:] else year = string[-1:-4:-1], month = string[-5:-7:-1], I'm not sure the reverse slicing is right here.)  Would something like this be faster than using regex?

Here an extract of the data:
array(['TEXT 11 2018', 'TEXT 12 2018', 'TEXT 1 2019', 'TEXT 2 2019',
'TEXT 3 2019', 'TEXT 4 2019', 'TEXT 5 2019', 'TEXT 6 2019',
'TEXT 7 2019', 'TEXT 9 2019', 'TEXT 10 2019', 'TEXT 11 2019',
'TEXT 12 2019', 'TEXT 01 2020', 'TEXT 02 2020', 'TEXT 03 2020',
'TEXT 05 2020', 'TEXT 06 2020', 'TEXT 07 2020', 'TEXT 09 2020',
'TEXT 10 2020', 'TEXT 11 2020', 'TEXT 12 2020', 'TEXT 2021 01',
'TEXT 2021 02', 'TEXT 2021 03', 'TEXT 2021 04', 'TEXT 2021 05',
'TEXT 2021 06', 'TEXT 2021 07', 'TEXT 2021 09', 'TEXT 2021 10',
'TEXT 2021 11', 'TEXT 2021 12', 'TEXT 2022 01', 'TEXT 2022 02',
'TEXT 2022 03', 'TEXT 2022 04', 'TEXT 2022 05', 'TEXT 2022 06',
'TEXT 2022 07', 'TEXT 2022 09', 'TEXT 2022 10', 'TEXT 2022 11',
'TEXT 2022 12', 'TEXT 1 2023', 'TEXT 2 2023', 'TEXT 3 2023',
'TEXT 4 2023', 'TEXT 5 2023', 'TEXT 6 2023', 'TEXT 7 2023',
'TEXT 9 2023', 'TEXT 10 2023'], dtype=object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# minimal reproducible example
data = {'Scenario': ['TEXT 01 2020', 
                     'TEXT 2021 01', 
                     'TEXT 1 2022', 
                     'TEXT 2023 1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

tmp = df['Scenario'].str.rsplit(pat=' ', n=2, expand=True).iloc[:,1:]

df['YearMonth'] = pd.PeriodIndex(np.where(tmp[1].str.len().eq(4), 
                                          tmp[1] + tmp[2].str.zfill(2), 
                                          tmp[2] + tmp[1].str.zfill(2)
                                          ), 
                                 freq='m')

df

       Scenario YearMonth
0  TEXT 01 2020   2020-01
1  TEXT 2021 01   2021-01
2   TEXT 1 2022   2022-01
3   TEXT 2023 1   2023-01
```

**Explanation**

1. Use [`Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `pat=' '`, `n=2` and `expand=True`, select the last two columns (`1, 2`) with [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), and assign the `df` to a temp variable (here: `tmp`).
2. Now, use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and check [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) equals 4 (with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)). Where `True`, we select `tmp[1] + tmp[2].str.zfill(2)`; where `False`, we reverse the columns. We use [`Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to prepend zeros where necessary for the months.
3. Finally, we apply `pd.PeriodIndex` to the `Series` obtained in step 2.

Comment: I like it.  I continued to work on it and was heading in this same direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: First convert to datetime using `to_datetime`, then convert to the desired format. `to_datetime` is smart enough to recognize the different formats, but i'm not sure about the efficiency compared to regexes.

For example

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(["Text 01 2018", "Text 2 2019", "Text 2020 03", "Text 2021 4"])
df = df.str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1]).dt.strftime("%Y%m")
```

gives

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Text | 201801 |
| Text | 201902 |
| Text | 202003 |
| Text | 202104 |

Comment: I didn't realize that to_datetime would be able to treat both year month and month year correctly.  I'll have to do the timings to see if this approach is faster or not.  Thanks!

Comment: I needed to add ",format='mixed'" to the 'to_datetime' method, to avoid an error. df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1],format='mixed').dt.to_period('M')

Comment: @higrm Interesting, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I using an online python compiler that uses 2.1.1 pandas version. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach of capturing 4 groups, you can slightly adjust the pattern and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) :

```
s = (
    df["Scenario"].str.replace(
        r"(?:\w+)\s+(?:(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{4})|(\d{4})\s+(\d{1,2}))",
        lambda m: f"{m.group(2)}{m.group(1).zfill(2)}" if m.group(1)
        else f"{m.group(3)}{m.group(4).zfill(2)}", regex=True
    )#.pipe(pd.PeriodIndex, freq="M") # uncomment to make periods
)

# df["Scenario"] = s # or df["New_Scenario"] = s # or whatever possible
```

Or this variant using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) inside a *listcomp* :

```
fn = (
    lambda m: f"{m.group(2)}{m.group(1).zfill(2)}" if m.group(1)
    else f"{m.group(3)}{m.group(4).zfill(2)}"
)

pat = re.compile(r"(?:\w+)\s+(?:(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{4})|(\d{4})\s+(\d{1,2}))")

lst = [pat.sub(fn, s) for s in df["Scenario"]]
```

> Demo : [[*regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/XhJP3x/1)]

Output :

```
print(s)

0     201811
1     201812
2     201901
3     201902
4     201903
       ...  
49    202305
50    202306
51    202307
52    202309
53    202310
Name: Scenario, dtype: object
```

On `df["Scenario"].sample(frac=2_000_000 / 54, replace=True)`, it took :

```
# higrm (with fixed pattern & apply)
# 1.96 s ± 24.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# ouroboros1 (without pd.PeriodIndex)
# 2.68 s ± 185 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# MennoK (with format="mixed")
# 5.72 s ± 330 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Timeless (replace)
# 1.43 s ± 17.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Timeless (listcomp)
# 1.16 s ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And here is a perfplot :

[image]

Comment: As I know, split operations in pandas can be quite expensive. Don't hesitate to provide a feedback based on your actual dataset ;)

Comment: We ran the four solutions on our data set and the fastest solution, by a factor of 2 was the MennoK solution.  This may be the result of the aged pandas version installed, I believe it is only 1.1.7.  So, this probably isn't indicative of results others may get.